# avoid force unwrapping inside a filter closure in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I am trying to filter array of [String?] with "abc".

```
// keysForAutoComplete: [String?]
let tempFilteredResult = keysForAutoComplete.filter { ($0?.contains("abc"))! }
```

How can I avoid force unwrapping within the closure ? I know about if let and guard let statements, but not quite sure how to apply them here?

Comment: What are the contents of `keysForAutoComplete`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 optional string

Comment: like ["abcd", "kjm", "babc", nil] ?

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes. vacawama's answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid force unwrapping by directly comparing to `true`:

```
let tempFilteredResult = keysForAutoComplete.filter { $0?.contains("abc") == true }
```

or by using the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap the result:

```
let tempFilteredResult = keysForAutoComplete.filter { $0?.contains("abc") ?? false }
```

or by using the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap the input:

```
let tempFilteredResult = keysForAutoComplete.filter { ($0 ?? "").contains("abc") }
```

---

**Explanation:**

`$0?.contains("abc")` is using *optional chaining* and the result is a `Bool?` which is `nil` if the element is `nil` or `Optional(true)` or `Optional(false)` depending on whether the `String` contains `"abc"`.  You can compare a `Bool?` to a `Bool`, so comparing to `true` will return `true` only when there is a `String` that contains `"abc"`.

The *nil coalescing operator* unwraps the value if it is not `nil`, or replaces it with the supplied default value if it is `nil`.  Since you want a `nil` item to return `false` for the comparison, the way to safely unwrap is to use `?? false`.

In the third example, the *nil coalescing operator* unwraps the value from `tempFilteredResult` replacing it with the empty string `""` if it is `nil`.

---

If you'd like the result to be `[String]`, you can use `compactMap` along with the *trinary operator* `?:` to generate an array of `[String]`:

```
let tempFilteredResult = keysForAutoComplete.compactMap { $0?.contains("abc") == true ? $0 : nil }
```

**Explanation:**

Here, `?:` is used to return the original value if it contains `"abc"` or `nil` if it does not.  `compactMap` then eliminates the `nil` values and unwraps the `String?` to return a `[String]`.

Comment: as the first syntax is more elegant and easier to follow, let say there a nil in the array and I use == true. What did you mean by saying ??false is safer? I tried using ==true on an array that had a nil value and it did not crash.

Comment: Both are equally safe.  The first isn't unwrapping the optional.  It is comparing the optional to `true` to create a new `Bool`.  `?? false` unwraps the optional.  Either work; use the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compactMap` operator to remove `nil` values and left your array as `[String]` type, so every element will be a non-optional value. After that, you can use `filter` on the new array. This way, you don't need to be worried about nil values, then unwrapping is no needed.

```
let keysForAutoComplete = ["abc", "ab", nil, "bca", "abcd"]
let tempFilteredResult = keysForAutoComplete.compactMap{$0}.filter{$0.contains("abc")}
```